# How can i get the call-sid from response of callback in twilios AddOn's "IBM Watson"

Tags: node.js, express, twilio, ibm-watson, ibm-speech-to-text

We enable the Twilios AddOn "IBM Watson Speech to Text" for recording transcribe.and we set our server webhook while enabling the addon. Now twilio calling webhook once call is completely done. after completing call twilio give response in that webhook In Nodejs.For handling that call response we need "Call Sid".In webhook response we cannot get "callSid".So how we can identify that response is for this particular call...?

anyone help me to how can find call-sid in response?

Callback response is

```
{
    "status": "successful",
    "message": null,
    "code": null,
    "results": {
        "ibm_watson_speechtotext": {
            "request_sid": "**************",
            "status": "successful",
            "message": null,
            "code": null,
            "payload": [{
                "content_type": "application/json",
                "url": "*************/Data"
            }],
            "links": {
                "add_on_result": "***********/Accounts/********/Recordings/**********/AddOnResults/******",
                "payloads": "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/******/Recordings/*******/AddOnResults/******/Payloads",
                "recording": "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/******/Recordings/*******"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

When you get the Add-on result it comes as part of the [Twilio voice webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#twilios-request-to-your-application), with all the normal [request parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#request-parameters) as well as an extra `AddOns` parameter which contains the JSON that you have shared above.

Webhook requests from Twilio are in the format `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and then within the `AddOns` parameter the data is a JSON string. In a (Ruby-like) pseudo code, you can access the call sid and the add on data like this:

```rb
post "/webhook" do
  call_sid = params["CallSid"]
  add_on_json = params["AddOns"]
  add_on_data = JSON.parse(add_on_json)
 
  # return TwiML
end
```

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question.
Actually i'm using "IBM Watson Speech to Text" in Nodejs and i was getting response when call hang up. And after "call-recording" route means bottom last. In that case we cant get any parameter as you said.

Comment: How and when are you making the request to the IBM Watson API? Can you update your question with your code?

Comment: We have enabled the IBM Watson Speech to Text addon in Twilio for recording transcribe and we have set the our server webhook while enabling the addon.

Now Twilio is calling that webhook once call is completely done.

But in our webhook we are not getting any call related information so we can not identify that webhook called for which call.

So my point is that what are the unique thing in that webhook using that we can identify that response is for this particular call.

Comment: Ok, that’s odd. As I describe in my answer above, you should receive the callback with parameters like `CallSid` to identify the call. If you are not receiving those parameters I would raise it  with Twilio support.

Comment: we don't receive any parameter expect requestId as i mention in question "callback response"

Comment: So I recommend you get in touch with Twilio support.

Comment: ok ill submit ticket in twilio and i request you would raise it with Twilio support.